# Python error: cannot astype a datetimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [bool]

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having a problem where im trying to filter data depending on some datetime values. I have 2 conditions. If I apply only 1 condition (either one) it runs without an error. But if I put both conditions seperated by a '&' then I get the error mentioned in the title.

I tried making sure the logic made sense, but i'm not sure if I have to convert the value of the output condition to something because i'm using 2?

filter2 = filter1[filter1['driver_loss_date_recode'] < filter1['driver_termination_date_recode_2'] & filter1['driver_loss_date_recode'] > filter1['driver_hire_date_recode']]

I want to filter data based on the two conditions specified.

Answer (score 0):

Single `&` is bit-wise operation:

```py
>>> bin(10)
'0b1010'
>>> bin(4)
'0b100'
>>> 4 & 10
0
```

Logical AND in python is just `and`:

```py
>>> if True or False:
...     print("foo")
... 
foo
>>> if True and False:
...     print("bar")
... 
>>> if not False:
...     print("baz")
... 
baz
```